# Completeness of the space of sets with distance defined by the measure of symmetric difference

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, metric-spaces, lebesgue-measure

Let $m$ be the measure defined on the set semiring $\mathfrak{S}_m$ and $m'$ its extension to the minimal ring $\mathfrak{R}(\mathfrak{S}_m)$. I read that $m'(A\triangle B)$ can be used as a distance in $\mathfrak{R}(\mathfrak{S}_m)$.

I would rather say that it can be used as a distance in the quotient $\mathfrak{R}(\mathfrak{S}_m)/\sim$ where we identify $A\sim A'$ when $m'(A\triangle A')=0$ [*EDIT* Mar 7'15: which is an equivalence relation, I would say, thanking future answerers for confirming or refuting this]: am I right?

I also [read](http://librarum.org/book/10022/144), in Kolmogorov-Fomin's *Elements of theory of functions and functional analysis*, that, with such a metric, the space $\mathfrak{M}$ of Lebesgue measurable sets, where $A$ and $A'$ are identified when $\mu(A\triangle A')=0$,  is complete, but I cannot see why, if $\{A_n\}\subset\mathfrak{M}$ is a sequence such that$$\forall\varepsilon>0\quad\exists N\in\mathbb{N}^+:\forall n,m\geq N\quad\mu(A_n\triangle A_m)<\varepsilon$$then a measurable $A$ must exists such that $\forall\varepsilon>0\quad\exists N\in\mathbb{N}^+:\forall n\geq N\quad\mu(A_n\triangle A)<\varepsilon$.

EDIT: Care Bear, whom I thank very much, has provided a proof for the case that $\bigcup_n A_n\in\mathfrak{M}$. According to Kolmogorov-Fomin's, $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is Lebesgue-measurable only under the restrictive condition that $\exists K\geq 0:\forall N\in\mathbb{N}^+\quad\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n)\leq K$ (problem 5 (b) [here](http://librarum.org/book/10022/145)). Can anybody explain whether the lemma is valid in any case?

I $\infty$-ly thank you all for any answer!!!

Comment: Thank you so much!!! The book has never made any mention of $L^1$ at the point where this interesting fact is stated: http://librarum.org/book/10022/144 :-( And I also see that, when it will discuss it, it will define it in a much less abstract way. Nevertheless, I suspect that, since $\mathfrak{M}$ must be a $\delta$-ring, we can use the corollary to theorem 11 at p. 267, which I think I've been able to prove in this more general case, which is the only case of limit concerning sets dealt with by the book; anyhow, I'm not sure how to use it...

Comment: FYI, I gave several references and applications to this metric in this [13 May 2005 sci.math post](http://mathforum.org/kb/message.jspa?messageID=3767449). See especially the paragraph beginning with "Note: This metric space has a number of interesting uses". I think this metric originated from Nikodym in the late 1920s, but I don't have my notes on this topic with me now to look it up. Finally, in that 2005 post I mention how to prove completeness in the paragraph that begins with "ADDITIONAL FACT: M[0,1] is a complete metric space".

Comment: By coincidence, I was looking at a paper this weekend that makes use of this metric. See the top half of p. 35 of Harry Max Schaerf, [*On the continuity of measurable functions in neighborhood spaces*](http://purl.pt/2158), **Portugaliae Mathematica** 6 #1 (1947), 33-44. The paper is freely available on the internet.

Comment: Thank you very much: I'll look at it!

Answer (score 8):

#### Quotient

Yes, you are right: in order for the distance to be a metric, and not just a "pseudometric", we need to take the quotient by the equivalence relation that you stated.

#### Completeness

Let's write  $d(A,B)=\mu(A\triangle B)$. To prove completeness of the space, it suffices to show that every sequence $A_n$ with $$d(A_n,A_{n+1})\le 2^{-n}\tag1$$ has a limit. This is a general metric space fact: from any Cauchy sequence one can extract a subsequence with property (1), and therefore obtain the convergence of the whole Cauchy sequence.

Let $B_n=\bigcup_{m\ge n }A_m$ and $C_n=\bigcap_{m\ge n}A_m$; both these sequences are nested. From (1), summing a geometric series,  we obtain $d(A_n,B_n)\le 2^{1-n}$ and $d(A_n,C_n)\le 2^{1-n}$. Hence $\mu(B_n\setminus C_n)\le 2^{2-n}$. Let $E=\bigcap B_n$. Since $C_n\subset A_n\subset B_n$ and $C_n\subset E\subset B_n$, it follows that $$
\mu(A_n\triangle E) \le \mu(B_n\setminus C_n)\to 0 
$$
which proves $\lim A_n=E$ when $\mathfrak{M}$ is a $\sigma$-algebra.

Comment: I find the explicit construction of $E$ fascinating. I don't understand a pair of things: why, if any subsequence satisfying (1) converges to $E$, then the sequence  converge to $E$? why $\mu(\bigcup_{m\geq n+1}B_m)=d(A_n,B_n)\leq 2^{1-n}$ and $\mu(A_n\setminus\bigcap_{m\geq n}A_m)=d(A_n,C_n)\leq 2^{1-n}$? $\infty$ thanks!

Comment: (A) If a Cauchy sequence has a convergent subsequence, then it converges [exercise with definition of limit and Cauchy].  (B)   I did not say that $\mu(\bigcup_{m\geq n+1}B_m)=d(A_n,B_n)$, and this is not true.  Rather, I use $B_n\setminus A_n \subset \bigcup_{m\ge n} (A_{m+1}\setminus A_m)$. If a point is in $B_n$ but not in $A_n$, there is some set $A_{m+1}$ where it first appeared.

Comment: Thank you so much again!!! I had misunderstood what $A_n\triangle B_n$ is. (A) is a very useful lemma: I've proven and pencil written it on the margin (though I'm not Fermat). As to the other majoration, I see that $A_n\triangle C_n\subset\bigcup_{m\geq n}A_m\setminus A_{m+1}$, so I understand.

Comment: I realise you consider countable unions like $B_n$ as belonging to $\mathfrak{M}$, which I suspect not to be possible in general if ours is not a unitary ring ($\mathfrak{M}$ would be a $\delta$-ring, but not a $\sigma$-algebra): please correct me if I'm wrong. Does the lemma apply only to unitary rings $\mathfrak{R}(\mathfrak{S}_m)$ or also to non-unitary rings? $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty$ thank$_n$! ;-)

Comment: Everything happens within $\bigcup A_n$, which is a set of finite measure. You can restrict all considerations to this set, thus obtaining a unit.

Comment: You're very kind! I tried to verify that, but I didn't succeed... Why $\bigcup_n A_n\in\mathfrak{M}$? I tried to use the fact that $\{A_n\}$ is Cauchy, therefore bounded, i.e. I know that $\exists S\in\mathfrak{M}:\mu(A_n\triangle S)\leq K$ for some $K\geq 0$, but that hasn't helped me... Thank you again!

Comment: I read in your question that $\mathfrak{M}$ is the space of Lebesgue measurable sets. The countable union of Lebesgue measurable sets is Lebesgue measurable. And I'm only kind enough to post 3 follow-up comments, which means this is the last one.

Comment: According to Kolmogorov-Fomin's $\bigcup_{n=1}^\infty A_n$ is Lebesgue-measurable if and only if $\mu(\bigcup_{n=1}^N A_n)$ is bounded by a constant independent from $N$: http://librarum.org/book/10022/145